# Binding an onclick event to an anchor tag with children and getting attrubute data from the anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a situation where I have attached an `onclick` event to an anchor tag, but it has a `span` tag inside as a child; hence when I do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="toggle js-toggle" data-target-cat="3">
    <span class="icon-angle-down"></span>
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.js-toggle').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var cat_id = $(e.target).data('target-cat');

});
```

It doesn't work as `e` represents the `span` element; sure I can just put the attribute on the span again, but I am paranoid that sometimes the `anchor` *may* trigger it rather than the `span` and I don't want to duplicate the attribute on both elements.

So I decided to do this:

```
$('.js-toggle').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var cat_id = $(e.target).data('target-cat');

    if (typeof cat_id === "undefined") {
        // Seems the click was triggered by a child of the anchor tag; grab it from the parent
        cat_id = $(e.target).parent().data('target-cat');
    }

});
```

This works, however I'm not overly comfortable doing it this way as what happens if the children elements change inside the anchor.

Is there a more consistent way of doing this or should I perhaps put the `onclick` event on the `span` tag instead?

**Bonus Question:** Why does `e.preventDefault();` work if `e` represents the `span` tag and not the `anchor`?

Comment: Use e.delegateTarget or e.currentTarget instead of e.target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) which references the element the event was initiated for. But what you want is to access the element you registered the event handler on - see [event.currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/).

For your "bonus question" you need to understand that the default action can be prevented on any element at anytime during the capture or bubble phase. That said, because you registered the event handler on the `<a>`, that's where you're preventing the default, not on the the `<span>` as you assumed.

Answer (score 3):

Try `$(this)` instead of `$(e.target)`:

```
$('.js-toggle').on('click', function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();    
    var cat_id = $(this).data('target-cat');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your bonus question:
e.preventDefault() works because the event is on the anchor tag and not on the span element. As you can see here, you're calling the on click event on $('.js-toggle') which stands for the anchor tag.